# Create a dictionary with multiple Split of data frame from big uneven Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a messy big CSV file with lot of Nan values and I read the dataframe using `pd.read_csv(file, names = range(int))`. I wanted to split this data into multiple dataframe and store in dictionary using given key in data. I prepared a simple example to explain my problem.

***Example rawdata***: My data looks like similarly as given but with more number of columns and rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df.loc[0,:] =  ['Home -AA',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[1,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df.loc[2,:] = ['Home time1',1, 2, 3]
df.loc[3,:] = ['Home time2',4, 5, 6]
df.loc[4,:] = ['Home time3',7, 8, 9]
df.loc[5,:] = ['sum',11,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[6,:] = ['agg',12,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[7,:] = ['max',6,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[8,:] = ['min',8,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[9,:] = ['med',1,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[10,:] =  ['Home -BB',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[11,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df.loc[12,:] = ['Home time1',11, 12, 13]
df.loc[13,:] = ['Home time2',14, 15, 16]
df.loc[14,:] = ['Home time3',17, 18, 19]
df.loc[15,:] = ['sum',101,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[16,:] = ['agg',122,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[17,:] = ['max',62,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[18,:] = ['min',83,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[19,:] = ['med',12,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[20,:] =  ['Home -CC',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[21,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df.loc[22,:] =  ['Home -DD',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[23,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df.loc[24,:] =  ['Home -EE',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[25,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df.loc[26,:] =  ['Home -FF',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[27,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df.loc[28,:] = ['Home time1',211, 212, 213]
df.loc[29,:] = ['Home time1',212, 213, 214]
df.loc[30,:] = ['sum',115,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[31,:] = ['agg',124,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[32,:] = ['max',65,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[33,:] = ['min',85,np.nan , np.nan] 
df.loc[34,:] = ['med',16,np.nan , np.nan]
```

***Wanted Results***: I want to convert this data frame into multiple data frame with define house keys and store as in dictionary dict1. (Result example)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df1.loc[1,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df1.loc[2,:] = ['Home time1',1, 2, 3]
df1.loc[3,:] = ['Home time2',4, 5, 6]
df1.loc[4,:] = ['Home time3',7, 8, 9]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df2.loc[11,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df2.loc[12,:] = ['Home time1',11, 12, 13]
df2.loc[13,:] = ['Home time2',14, 15, 16]
df2.loc[14,:] = ['Home time3',17, 18, 19]


df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df3.loc[21,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']

df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df4.loc[23,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']

df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df5.loc[25,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']

df6 = pd.DataFrame(columns=([1,2,3,4]))
df6.loc[27,:] =  ['place/time','value1','value2','value3']
df6.loc[28,:] = ['Home time1',211, 212, 213]
df6.loc[29,:] = ['Home time1',212, 213, 214]

dict1 = {'House -AA':df1, 'House -BB': df2,'House -CC': df3 , 'House -DD':df4, 'House -EE':df5, 'House -FF':df6}
```

Prepared the code using for loop but I cannot able to split all the data frame in correct way. If I do not break the loop then I will receive an error of (List index out of range). Can you please help me to get similar results as I explained above?

***Prepared code idea***:

```
namesplit = lambda x: x.split('-')[0]
postion = 'Home '
rawname = []
for i in df[1]:
    x = namesplit(i)
    if postion == x:
        rawname.append(i)
        
test = {}
for i in range(len(rawname)):
    x = df[df[1]==rawname[i]].index.values
    y = df[df[1]==rawname[i+1]].index.values
    if y == len(df) -9:
        break
    df_1 = df.iloc[x[0]:y[0], :]
    test[rawname[i]] = df_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `groupby` and `cumsum`:

```
result = {}

for _, i in df.groupby(df[1].str.startswith("Home -").cumsum()):
    name, d = i[1].iat[0], i.iloc[1:]
    result[name] = d[~d[1].isin(["sum","agg","max","min","med"])]

print (result)

{'Home -AA':             1       2       3       4
1  place/time  value1  value2  value3
2  Home time1       1       2       3
3  Home time2       4       5       6
4  Home time3       7       8       9, 
'Home -BB':              1       2       3       4
11  place/time  value1  value2  value3
12  Home time1      11      12      13
13  Home time2      14      15      16
14  Home time3      17      18      19, 
'Home -CC':              1       2       3       4
21  place/time  value1  value2  value3, 
'Home -DD':              1       2       3       4
23  place/time  value1  value2  value3, 
'Home -EE':              1       2       3       4
25  place/time  value1  value2  value3, 
'Home -FF':              1       2       3       4
27  place/time  value1  value2  value3
28  Home time1     211     212     213
29  Home time1     212     213     214}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by looping through the full dataframe and emitting smaller dataframes on the delimiter rows. It's brute force but works.

```
results = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if "Home -" in row[1]:
        accumulator = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1, 2, 3, 4])
        key = row[1]
        results[key] = accumulator
    else:
        results[key] = results[key].append(row)
```

Output:

```
In [9]: results
Out[9]:
{'Home -AA':             1       2       3       4
 1  place/time  value1  value2  value3
 2  Home time1       1       2       3
 3  Home time2       4       5       6
 4  Home time3       7       8       9
 5         sum      11     NaN     NaN
 6         agg      12     NaN     NaN
 7         max       6     NaN     NaN
 8         min       8     NaN     NaN
 9         med       1     NaN     NaN,
 'Home -BB':              1       2       3       4
 11  place/time  value1  value2  value3
 12  Home time1      11      12      13
 13  Home time2      14      15      16
 14  Home time3      17      18      19
 15         sum     101     NaN     NaN
 16         agg     122     NaN     NaN
 17         max      62     NaN     NaN
 18         min      83     NaN     NaN
 19         med      12     NaN     NaN,
 'Home -CC':              1       2       3       4
 21  place/time  value1  value2  value3,
 'Home -DD':              1       2       3       4
 23  place/time  value1  value2  value3,
 'Home -EE':              1       2       3       4
 25  place/time  value1  value2  value3,
 'Home -FF':              1       2       3       4
 27  place/time  value1  value2  value3
 28  Home time1     211     212     213
 29  Home time1     212     213     214
 30         sum     115     NaN     NaN
 31         agg     124     NaN     NaN
 32         max      65     NaN     NaN
 33         min      85     NaN     NaN
 34         med      16     NaN     NaN}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the List index out of range error is that `y` in your loop is using `i+1`th value of your list `rawname`. So you only want to loop till `len(rawname)-1` as follows:

```
test = {}
for i in range(len(rawname)-1):
    x = df[df[1]==rawname[i]].index.values
    y = df[df[1]==rawname[i+1]].index.values
    df_1 = df.iloc[x[0]:y[0], :]
    test[rawname[i]] = df_1
```